# Odd data type issue

Tags: c++, variables, lua, int

I'm quite new to C++ and I don't understand what is going on. I am trying to cast a Lua `double` arg. data type to the `uint8_t`. Application is compiling without any issues - however when, I dont get any results from the variable - just like it was empty.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sstream>
#include "lua.h"

using namespace std;
int _lua_function(lua_State* L) {
     int step = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
     ostringstream oss;
     oss << "Step is:" << step;
     return 0;
}
```

Output is: `Step is: 22`

When I change the

```
int step = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
```

to

```
uint8_t step = static_cast<uint8_t> (lua_tonumber(L, 1));
```

The output becomes : `Step is:`

Why I am getting no results from the variable just because of the data type change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that `uint8_t` on your platform is same as `unsigned char`. When an `unsigned char` with value `22` is inserted into an `ostringstream`, you don't see `22` in the output but the character that is represented by `22`, which is a non-printable character.

You can try

```
uint8_t s = 22;
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

to see the same effect.

Comment: You're right I guess: http://i.imgur.com/m00gC3f.png :-). So the solution is to use the nearest integer which is `int64_t` - right?

Comment: When you convert a `double` to an integral type, you have to be very careful about the range of values the integral type can hold. `int32_t` might be adequate but then `int64_t` might not be adequate. It all depends on the range of values you are dealing with. Checkout http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits.